# Python joining list elements in a tricky way

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So, I have this list

```
l = ['abc', 'retro', '', '', 'images', 'cool', '', 'end']
```

and, I want to join them in a way such as:

```
l = ['abc retro', '', '', 'images cool', '', 'end']
```

I tried lots of methods but nothing seemed to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a list comprehension. Group into `''`s and non `''` and join items from the latter using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). The ternary operator in the rear of the comprehension uses the group key to decide what to do for each group:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['abc','retro','','','images','cool','','end']

r = [j for k, g in groupby(l, lambda x: x=='') 
                          for j in (g if k else (' '.join(g),))]
print(r)
# ['abc retro', '', '', 'images cool', '', 'end']
```

Comment: just perfect..!

Comment: You can simplify that (and speed it up) by replacing the lambda by `bool`, and reversing the test in the inner loop: `r = [j for k, g in groupby(l, bool) for j in ([' '.join(g)] if k else g)]`. `bool` is implemented in C so it _should_ be faster than calling a Python function (the lambda).

Answer (score 4):

Here's another version using good old while loops to edit the list in place:

```
In [6]: l=['abc','retro','','','images','cool','','end']

In [7]: i = 1
   ...: while i < len(l):
   ...:     while l[i-1] and l[i]:
   ...:         l[i-1] += ' ' + l[i]
   ...:         del l[i]
   ...:     i += 1
   ...:

In [8]: l
Out[8]: ['abc retro', '', '', 'images cool', '', 'end']
```

Comment: I'll pay that, although mutating the source list _may_ not be desirable, but I guess it's ok here, since the OP is assigning the modified list back to `l`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.chain` and `itertools.groupby()` with `bool` as the key-function:

```
In [21]: from itertools import groupby, chain

In [22]: list(chain.from_iterable([' '.join(g)] if k else g for k, g in groupby(lst, bool)))
Out[22]: ['abc retro', '', '', 'images cool', '', 'end']
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using lambda functions with list comprehension  you could do it the old fashion way by just iterating through the lists.

```
l=['abc','retro','','','images','cool','','end']

result = list()
for x in range(len(l)):
    if l[x]:
        #Its not empty lets move to next until we find one or more consecutive non empty elements
        for y in range(x+1, len(l)):
            if l[y]:
                result.append(l[x]+' '+l[y])
                x = y

            else:
                x = y
                break
    else:
        result.append(l[x])

    #We are going to append last element, because we might have read an empty before
    if x == len(l)-1:
        result.append(l[x])

print result
```

^^ The solution above is not correct, and would only fit this case.

Here is another generic approach using a stack approach

```
l=['abc','retro','','','images','are','cool','','end']

result = list()
previous = ''
while l:
    current = l.pop(0)
    if current:
        if previous:
            previous+=' '+current
        else:
            previous = current
    else:
        result.append(previous)
        result.append('')
        previous = ''

result.append(current)
print result
```

Comment: This doesn't work so well if there are more than two words in a row, eg, `l=['abc','retro','','','images','are','cool','','end']`, or if `l` ends in an empty string.

Comment: Yes you are correct, also forgot about iterators in python. Will update post with another solution

Comment: The new version is better, but it still has a few problems. It adds extra empty strings, and it does't handle the end of the list properly. You can fix it by changing `result.append(previous)` to `if previous: result.append(previous)`, and replace `result.append(current)` with `if previous: result.append(previous)` too. Also, `.pop(0)` is ver inefficient because all the subsequent list items have to get moved down after the first one's deleted. It's much better to do `for current in l:`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `groupby` approach. It doesn't use a list comp, but I think that makes it a little more readable. ;) And unlike the other (current)  answers it uses a single loop rather than nested loops (apart from the loop that `.join` uses internally).

We use `bool` as the key function, so the groups are either true-ish or false-ish. A false-ish group is a group of empty strings, so we extend the output list `new` with the group. A true-ish group contains only non-empty strings, so we join it, and append the result to `new`.

```
from itertools import groupby

old = ['abc', 'retro', '', '', 'images', 'cool', '', 'end']

new = []
for k, g in groupby(old, key=bool):
    if k:
        new.append(' '.join(g))
    else:
        new.extend(g)

print(new)
```

**output**

```
['abc retro', '', '', 'images cool', '', 'end']
```